# .pages.xml - jboss restart

Tags: ant, jboss, seam

I use an ant script for my seam application to explode or deploy the project.

The problem is that it also deploys some temp file: **.pages.xml** in my WEB-INF directory which
makes JBOSS server to cycle..

Do you know what can be the cause or how can I avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you ant script is using a `<copy>` target, with a fileset including `**/*`. This will copy every single file, including "hidden" files (the ones starting with a dot). To avoid, I'd suggest to include only the patterns you know you'll need (whitelist), like, `**/*xhtml`, `**/*class` and so on. Or you can use a blacklist approach, which would be to include everything and add a "exclude" set with `**/.*` (which would then remove the hidden files).

Answer (score 1):

Use [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) and you don't have to deploy your application again. It will hot deploy everything so that you don't need to restart JBoss.

I wrote a very small blog about it [here](http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-reduce-your-re-deployment.html)